# How to retrieve a Javascript value that doesn't have a subclass

Tags: javascript, html, information-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a Javascript that does not have a subclass. In this case, I am trying to retreive the "Today" value:

```html
<div class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter">
    <div>Today</div>
```

Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Also, is `<div>Today</div>` the *very* next element after the element with `class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"`? It makes a big difference in answering your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Sometimes that element is not the first element in the subclass. Example: here I need the (30+ days ago) <div class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"><div class="icl-u-textColor--success">Canadian Job Bank</div><div>30+ days ago</div><div id="originalJobLinkContainer" class="icl-u-lg-inline icl-us-xs-hide"

Comment: Are you not allowed to modify the HTML? If you don't add a hook to your HTML, your query will be brittle and very likely to break as your HTML evolves.

Comment: You may want to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 3):

You can use selector: `.jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter>div`

```js
console.log($(".jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter>div").first().text());

console.log(document.querySelector(".jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter>div").innerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter">
  <div>Today</div>
</div>
```

**Updated:** use 2 ways by jQuery and javascript.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more specific: there are other child classes as well, and I need a specific one 

like here, I need the second one (30+ days ago)

<div class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter">
<div class="icl-u-textColor--success">Canadian Job Bank</div>
<div>30+ days ago</div>
<div id="originalJobLinkContainer" class="icl-u-lg-inline icl-us-xs-hide"

Comment: @A_Sammy: `document.querySelector('jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter').children[1]`. You can access any child by index.

Comment: @FelixKling A better way `document.querySelector('jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter').firstElementChild` so you're not relying on whitespace.

Comment: @JuanMendes: OP want's the second child though. Why does `children[1]` rely on whitespace?

Comment: @Felix Sorry, got confused with [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) which creates text nodes out of whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

You can grab the text inside the child div like this.

```
var parent = Document.getElementsByClassName("jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter")[0];
var child = parent.childNodes;
var text = child[1].innerHTML;
```

Edit: Juan is absolutely right. I had the child index wrong previously.

Comment: Did you even try this? The first child of the div is a text node, so your `text` variable is set to `undefined`. You could use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild) if you really cannot add a hook to the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error @Juan